# Join a view table to other new view table

Tags: postgresql

Cab I join a view table to my new creating view table in PostgreSQL? I am using Left join for it.
What is pros and cons of using it?
Does it work enough fast for big database?

Comment: No problem. If you want to make fast processing your data doing index or store procedure better..

Comment: There is no such thing as a "view table". It's either a view or a table.

Comment: @DwiRahmanIsmail: why would a stored procedure (which Postgres doesn't yet have, only functions) improve performance. Very often, stored procedures (or functions) make things slower

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your sharing, knew that call in postgres function not procedure and can i ask? why procedure or function make things slower?

Comment: @DwiRahmanIsmail: why do you think it makes it faster?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please correct me if i am wrong, procedure make shorter and faster query so i think that make faster to process data.

Comment: @DwiRahmanIsmail: that assumption is wrong. A query that is rung through a stored function isn't faster just because you put it into a function (and I don't see how the query could magically be "shorter" just because you run it in a different way)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i want to make some question about this and please help answer it. Great thanks..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179361/discussion-between-dwi-rahman-ismail-and-a-horse-with-no-name).